Micronaut login redirecting from a docker container
I have a pair of Micronaut services secured via a Keycloak docker image. Running it normally, via ./gradlew run it authenticates with Keycloak at localhost:9080 and can successfully do both standard and client_credentials flow. I more-or-less followed this guide, so I have a UI at localhost:8081 that authenticates via Keycloak.
I want to move my microservices into Docker, where it will share a Docker network with Keycloak and reach it at keycloak:9080. When I do this in practice, however, the login URL redirects to the Docker network host alias. That is /oauth/login/keycloak tries to point my docker to keycloak:8080, which cannot be resolved from the host.
If my explanation is unclear I have a branch  that should be able to walk you through it.
I'm looking into workarounds like proxies or messing with my hosts file, but the more lightweight solution is if there was a way to tell Micronaut to use a different host for Keycloak when doing login redirects. If my understanding of the standard flow is correct that should be possible here.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Add this --hostname-port=9080 to your keycloak start command.

Thank you.
--hostname-port is part of the deprecated hostname v1. In hostname v2 the --hostname option includes the host and port.
Since Keycloak itself is accessible as normal I don't think the solution will lay with any Keycloak options. This is a product of the interactions of Keycloak and Micronaut both being in Docker containers.
